# Java serial port cannot change speed on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, serial-port, raspberry-pi, data-transfer

I'm working on a project to send data between two Raspberry Pi's over a RS485 serial connection. For that I have written a little Java programm to send the data.
The setup is working, but I somehow cannot change the speed of my data transfer in the Java prog. I'm using a test file with 25kb of random data and two Raspberry Pi Model 1B. As a library I'm using the RXTX Java Library.

I've changed the settings in `/boot/config.txt` and `/boot/cmdline.txt` so I can use the serial port and change the speed.

To test whether the hardware can do it, I send some data with simple console commands. One Raspi sends:

```
cat 25kTestfile.txt > /dev/ttyAMA0
```

the other receives:

```
cat /dev/ttyAMA0 > 25kTestfile.txt
```

I changed the speed with `sudo stty`.
With this command line setup I can send data with up to 1Mbs and change the speed how I like it.

In my Java program, though, the speed does not change. No matter if I set the serial port to 115200 or 1000000 the speed at which it sends stays the same. With my program, sending the 25k takes a little under 3 sec, with the console 0.3 sec.

The Java program consists of two files. I've included the most important parts of the program below. One file to setup the serial port connection is here.

```
import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class SerialConnect {

  private SerialPort serialPort = null;
  private InputStream in = null;
  private OutputStream out = null;
  private CommPort commPort = null;
  private CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = null;

  void connect( String portName ) throws Exception {
    portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier
        .getPortIdentifier( portName );
    if( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() ) {
      System.out.println( "Error: Port is currently in use" );
    } else {
      int timeout = 2000;
      commPort = portIdentifier.open( this.getClass().getName(), timeout );

      if( commPort instanceof SerialPort ) {
        serialPort = ( SerialPort )commPort;
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams( 1000000,
                                        SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                                        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                                        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE );
        serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

        in = serialPort.getInputStream();
        out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

      } else {
        System.out.println( "Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example." );
      }
    }
  }

  [...]

  public void write(byte[] input) {
      try {
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
          this.out.write( input[i] );
        }
        this.out.flush();
      } catch( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public void write(byte input) {
      try {
         this.out.write(input);
      } catch( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }


  [...]

  public SerialConnect() {}

  public SerialConnect(String portName) {
    try{
      connect(portName);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error Failed to connect port.\n");
    }
  }
}
```

The other which uses the serial connection is here:

```
File outFile = new File("./25kTestfile.txt");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(outFile);
byte[] c = new byte[(int)outFile.length()];
in.read(c);
SerialConnect serialConnection = new SerialConnect("/dev/ttyAMA0"); 
if(serialConnection == null) {
    System.out.println("Could not open Serial port.\n");
    return;
}
serialConnection.write(c);
```

My Question is now: Why does the speed not change? Do I need to set some other things? Is it possible that Java is so slow on a Raspi that the send speed cannot be faster?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.
The write function I'm using to send the byte-Array was writing the data byte by byte to the OutputStream in a loop. This is apparently very inefficient.
I changed the write function to look like this now:

```
public void write(byte[] input) {
      try {
        this.out.write( input );  // no loop
        this.out.flush();
      } catch( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

This makes the send process about 10 times quicker.

So the problem was not that the speed of the connection was not changing, but that the function was not quick enough to feed enough data to the stream.